# SQL Express Connection Error When Connecting to Database

Tags: c#, sql, connection

[image]

I've been trying to connect my Visual basic to SQL because this is what we are taught off but when I execute it, it shows this. How do I fix this?

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.  Also Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Comment: The title says "Visual Basic", the screenshot shows C# code and SQL Server, and tags include "vba" and "mysql"!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. Your question has a low quality. What is your goal & your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, dev env & data structures, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), images or sketches of screens, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Answer (score 1):

This Windows user needs to be granted access to SQL Server and that specific database. It is usually configured during installation process of SQL Server. You can still do it by opening SSMS and adding this user under Security -> Logins node from Object Explorer panel.

Of course, to be able to do above, you need to connect to your SQL Server Express first. You may need to use another Windows user or a SQL Server user. The latter would be possible only if SQL Server Authentication has been enabled during installation process by choosing Mixed Mode for authentication (Windows + SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get *full permission* in SQL Server.

1. Open *SSMS* there is a **Security** folder then => **Logins**.
2. In **Logins** you will find your PC's *username* which is connected to Sql service
3. Right-click on your username => **Properties**
4. Check **Windows Authentication Mode**

Comment: _"..you need to get `full` permission..."_ - not necessarily. _"...in logins you will `find` your PC's username..."_ - perhaps, perhaps not.  Based on the error it sounds like the SQL login (Windows or not) isn't mapped for the specific database.  See **Delphi's** answer.   I think if you just add the database mapping steps you should be fine.

Comment: I tried it but I get an error when I execute it. I get an error on this code cn.Open(); and says login request failed